# how do I extend a class from another script in c# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to extend a base class on my player object.
player has damage script that looks like this

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Damage : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public int health = 100;

    public virtual void ReceiveDamage(int damageAmount)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Original");
    }
}
```

And then the same player has another script like this :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class playerDamage : Damage 
{
    public override void ReceiveDamage(int damageAmount)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Extended");     
    }
}
```

But when I call the script from a 3rd scrip on another object like this:

```
var damageScript = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Damage>();
if( damageScript)
{
    damageScript.ReceiveDamage(damageAmount);
}
```

the only response to the log is "Original"
Shouldn't the child be called and "Extended" written to the log?

Comment: Are you *sure* the instance returned is actually a `playerDamage`?

Comment: Please be aware the `Unity` tag refers to the Unity application block not the Unity3D game engine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. The easiest one is to **[SendMessage](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html)**.

```
collision.gameObject.SendMessage("ReceiveDamage", damageAmount);
```

Whatever implementation of `ReceivedDamage` that the collision GameObject has, that will be the one that is called. This is awesome because you don't need to specify the type yourself nor use GetComponent.

---

#### Important Extra Information

In any implementation that you choose the key step is to **make sure that the right script is attached** to the `collision.gameObject`. If you attach both scripts then you are playing with fire.

To avoid playing with fire please make `Damage` an `abstract` class.

```
public abstract class Damage : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public int health = 100;

    public virtual void ReceiveDamage(int damageAmount)
    {
       Debug.Log ("Original");
    }
}
```

Abstract will give you the same functionality you want, except that Unity3d won't let you attach `Damage` to the GameObjects, which is good to avoid mistakes. You will always have the option to have the original `ReceiveDamage` and the choice to override it on future classes that inherit from `Damage`, like this:

```
public class Example : Damage
{
    // This one still has ReceiveDamage but it happens in the base class.
}
```

or

```
public class PlayerDamage : Damage 
{
    public override void ReceiveDamage(int damageAmount)
    {
       Debug.Log("Extended");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think when you call this line:

```
var damageScript = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Damage>();
```

It gets the component by name, which in this case would be the Damage script, not the playerDamage script.

In you script it should be:

```
   var damageScript = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<playerDamage>();
   if( damageScript)
   {
       damageScript.ReceiveDamage(damageAmount);

   }
```

Comment: You are close, but `It instantiates the Damage class` is not correct.

Comment: From memory, does it just grab the component by name?

Comment: Yup, that's what it does.